# When on iPhone 5, UITableView cuts off in 3.5 inch format

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, iphone-5

For some reason, the `UITableView` cuts off when on an iPhone 5. Instead of seeing the table view on the entire screen, I just see a blue background. Basically, it's behaving like I'm using a 3.5" inch screen. The only time it does work is when I set the view to "Retina 4 Full Screen" in Simulated Metrics. But the problem with that is then I have the opposite problems with 3.5 inch screens. Here are a couple of pictures (the view is currently set to "Freeform" in Simulated Metrics):

[image]
[image]

I have tried looking for similar questions, but none have helped. If it helps, I do have a MainWindow.xib. I am testing this using the iPhone 6.0 Simulator as well as an iPhone 4S 16GB. I will update this question if anything looks unclear. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't have the proper autoresizing masks set. Try to set the mask to just `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Comment: I'm not too sure where to put that.

Comment: @Junior117 In the size inspector (http://i.stack.imgur.com/SzPi5.png) click on the two double arrows so that they light up in a stronger red.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what i did. I started my xib file size as 3.5 in attributes inspector

And in my view controller i have this code, make sure you change the frame in viewDidAppear method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if ([self hasFourInchDisplay]) {
        self.myTableView.frame = self.view.frame;
    }
}

- (BOOL)hasFourInchDisplay {
    return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize your table, add one property `autoresizingMask`.

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;
```

One more thing you are adding `tableView` inside `mainView(self.view)` or any subView. You may have this problem.

Check Your mainView's bound and frame.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Auto Layout you can just set constraints for the four margins of your table view then click add constraints

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these and see if they help:

```
myTableView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
// or
myTableView.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: In what file do I put that and where?